# How can I solve this Git LFS Simple Problem? LFS upload failed

Tags: git, git-lfs

I made an empty .git project.

**Step1**:USE COMMAND: `git lfs install`

**Step2:**
Put an logo.png in that project

**Step3:**
Commit and Push logo.png to remote git server,but get an error.**LFS upload failed**

**Question:
Why this logo.png will be tracked as lfs file when push to github?**

I haven't set any .gitattributes and run git track command.

But the file will be uploaded use lfs (not common git,stored in the lfs system)

How this happened? And How can I ban lfs when I Uploaded this logo.png file?

Comment: Please read the introduction to git lfs: https://git-lfs.github.com/

Answer (score 0):

My question was solved.

The answer is that logo.png is not a real png file in client.  **It is a LFS Descripter**.

**The LFS Descripter should be only exist in git server,but sometimes you may download and save it in client for some kind reasons.**

I made this error for downloading it from github zip ,**so make sure your client file is a real file**.